# After some time, NodeJS does not successfully insert data into MongoDB

Tags: html, css, node.js, mongodb

I have a label with input for hour, minutes and am/pm. I run the server with nodemon and I go to the local address. I add an hour with some text to the server and it works. I don't know what happened after this, but whatever I do, the time label input thing doesn't work anymore. I can't add anything unless the field with the hour is empty and if I leave it empty, then of course, it won't show anything.

I tested random code and it doesn't work, I literally copied a backup from github and it doesn't work? I don't know if it's relevant, but I pressed ctrl-c to close the server and pressed "n", as in, not close it, but it still closed, after that I think it didn't work anymore. I literally don't understand how it's possible that on other computer the server works fine, but if I run it from here, it doesn't work

I don't know, I can provide the whole repository for someone to test if it works, it just doesn't work for some reason on my computer

```
<div class = "addHour formContainer">
       <label for="formHour" class='formLabel'>Hour:</label>
               <input type="time" name="hour" id="formHour" autocomplete="off"  class="add" required>
                </div>
```

Comment: I am Unable to understand the situation with your explanation. I need a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.

Comment: I would prefer seeing the main server side code and the main client side page

Comment: Okay, I'll check it out and get back

Comment: Did you try it in some other browser (in the computer in which it was not working) just to make sure the server side code is fine

Comment: Yeah, it's the same in any browser, I don't know what I did that it doesn't work on my computer

Comment: Is your platform different in both computers (i.e., You may be using NodeJS 13 yours and NodeJS 14 in the other computer...)

Comment: It is the same, but I'll try to reinstall nodejs here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232130/discussion-between-atheesh-thirumalairajan-and-andrei-jarca).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some problem with the data in MongoDB,
Try executing the following:

- Open command prompt in windows and type `cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin` and then `mongo.exe` to open the MongoDB Command Line Shell
- As soon as it loads, type in `show dbs`
- Type use `weekly-scheduler` to go inside the database
- Then type `db.dropDatabase()` (Warning: This will delete all events which you have added from the weekly-scheduler app i.e., all content inside the weekly-scheduler database)

Comment: Thanks so much, I can't believe it worked finally